colcon build unresponsive, maxed out ram/cpu
I'm running ROS2 Humble and recently my computer has been freezing/becoming unresponsive in the middle of colcon build. The build is terminated or I have to force shutdown/restart my computer. Does anyone else experience this?
To ensure that the build completes, I have to build the project sequentially, which is SLOW. I referenced this post for the following command.
MAKEFLAGS="-j1 -l1" colcon build --executor sequential

I often encounter this issue, and upon investigation, I found that it's caused by insufficient memory. It can be resolved by increasing the swap space, which doesn't significantly affect the speed. The specific command is as follows:
cd ~
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=./.swap bs=1M count=8192
sudo chmod 600 ./.swap
sudo mkswap ./.swap
sudo swapon ./.swap

Please try again.

I'll try this out and let you know. Thanks!
